# Webpack css-loader cannot find index.js, style-loader cannot find addStyles.js

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

ERROR in ./app/index.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./../node_modules
css-loader/index.js in C:\Users\johnliang\Temp\webpack-angular/app
 @ ./app/index.scss 4:14-116 13:2-17:4 14:20-122

ERROR in ./app/index.scss
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve 'file' or 'directory' ./../node_modules
style-loader/addStyles.js in C:\Users\johnliang\Temp\webpack-angular/app
 @ ./app/index.scss 7:13-68

index.scss is not loaded in the final webpack output.

Comment: Can you provide your Webpack configuration? What do your imports look like?

Comment: I have the same error, did you find the solution?

Comment: I found same issue. Check out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41889869/cannot-find-module-css-loader-while-doing-ng-build-prod-with-angular-cli1-0-0/41970682#41970682)

Answer (score 22):

Be sure you use

> path.join(__dirname, 'src')

and not

> __dirname + '/src'

in your webpack.config.js:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
...
```

Comment: I had exactly the same issue, and this worked. im guessing it has to do with using the correct path separator for the OS

Comment: Not just for the `context` but `resolve.root` needs to have the proper slashes too.

Comment: @roman-d You sir just saved me like a day of debugging, thanks a lot!

Comment: i have having the same issue. Could you please let me know how to update the below code. const path = require("path");
const dist = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
const combineLoaders = require('webpack-combine-loaders');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './src/index.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: __dirname+'/public',
        publicPath: '/',
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue to this whereby my webpack build was complaining about a `.js` file:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/style-loader/lib/addStyles.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './urls' in '/Users/<user>/path/to/project/node_modules/style-loader/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/style-loader/lib/addStyles.js 64:14-31
```

I must have copied this solution from a tutorial somewhere along the way (or many), but comparing to another project I have written, I realised that I had missed the extension '.js' to the resolve property in my webpack config:

```
resolve: {
  extensions: [
    '.scss',
    '.css',
    '.js' // <-- HERE
  ]
},
```

This fixed the issue for me, so definitely give this a go.