# cannot find module css-loader while doing ng build -prod with angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.21

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, css-loader

I have following package.json configuration

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.2.1",
"@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
"@angular/core": "2.2.1",
"@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
"@angular/http": "2.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.2.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.2.1",
"@angular/router": "3.2.1",
"@angular2-material/button": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"@angular2-material/button-toggle": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"@angular2-material/card": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"@angular2-material/checkbox": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"@angular2-material/core": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"@angular2-material/grid-list": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"@angular2-material/icon": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"@angular2-material/input": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"@angular2-material/list": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"@angular2-material/menu": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"@angular2-material/progress-bar": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"@angular2-material/progress-circle": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"@angular2-material/radio": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"@angular2-material/sidenav": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"@angular2-material/slide-toggle": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"@angular2-material/slider": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"@angular2-material/tabs": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"@angular2-material/toolbar": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"@angular2-material/tooltip": "^2.0.0-alpha.8-2",
"ng2-material-dropdown":"0.5.4",
"ng2-toasty": "^2.2.2",
"@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.30",
"angular2-cookie": "1.2.3",
"angular2-material-datepicker": "^0.5.0",
"angulartics2": "^1.1.9",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"d3": "^4.3.0",
"es6-shim": "0.35.1",
"ng2-datetime-picker": "^0.11.3",
"ng2-tag-input": "0.6.0",
"ng2-auto-complete":"0.8.2",
"reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
"rickshaw": "^1.6.0",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
"zone.js": "^0.6.23",
"ng2-file-upload": "^1.1.4-2",
"angular2-color-picker": "^1.3.0",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "1.0.0-alpha.16"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
"@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
"angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.21",
"codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
"jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
"karma": "1.2.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
"karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
"karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
"karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
"protractor": "4.0.5",
"ts-node": "1.2.1",
"tslint": "3.13.0",
"typescript": "2.0.2",
"typings": "1.3.1"
```

}

`ng build -prod` was working fine, however all of a sudden the same configuration gives the following error

```
ERROR in ./src/styles.css
Module build failed: Error: Cannot find module '/Volumes/DATA/new-    clone-test/nbw/node_modules/css-loader/index.js?sourcemap&minimize'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:440:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:388:25)
at Module.require (module.js:468:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at loadLoader (/Volumes/DATA/new-clone-test/nbw/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/loadLoader.js:13:17)
```

I am not sure what causes this issue. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you have `css-loader` module installed?

Comment: Yes. It gets installed automatically.

Comment: Yes we are experiencing the same issue. We are also experiencing the same thing since today. Our assumption is that the css loader was updated automatically as it's a dependency of the angular-cli. We have been experimenting with various solutions all day to no result. So we are not going to attempt to change the css-loader version without our package.json

Answer (score 2):

I have got the same issue as you. As a temporary solution I changed to 'ng build --dev'. Using this command the loader uses webpack-build-development.js instead of webpack-build-production.js and gets 'css-loader?sourcemap' instead of 'css-loader?sourcemap&minimize'.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Florinache!

Downgrading to angular-cli "1.0.0-beta.19-3" works for me. I had the same issue from today on in all my projects...

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
       ...
       "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.19-3",
       ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

had the same issue starting today.

The solution I found was to change the angular-cli dependency in package.json file to "1.0.0-beta.19-3" and reinstall the npm packages.

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
       ...
       "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.19-3",
       ...
       }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I´m issuing the same problem in all internal packages from my work, since two or three days ago...

This is our version from angular-cli too, i open the package.json file and saw that the  webpack is configured as follows: `"@ngtools/webpack": "^1.0.0",`
...
and seeing the history of it with `npm view @ngtools/webpack time` i could observe that the lastest version *1.2.4* was released on 01-20-2017 (**seven days ago**)

I'm working on it rigth now, but i'm suspicious about this last released version...

Comment: There is a way to *force* angular-cli to use the version 1.2.3 of `@ngtools/webpack` on it?

Comment: Have you tried specifying the exact version you want to use? For example:"@ngtools/webpack": "1.2.4"?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [extract-text-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) is upgraded to RC, 
Try overriding the extract-text-webpack-plugin version to "2.0.0-beta.4" in your package.json.

Answer (score 1):

mkishorem is right.

I also got same error and fix with adding override code 
at package.json like below

```
"devDependencies": {
 "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0-beta.5" 
 }
```

no need to downgrading to angular-cli all.

Answer (score 0):

Update to @angular/* 2.3.1 version

Comment: Why? What's the problem and why does updating fix it?